# Where can I find the configuration files for Kdenlive?

Tags: kdenlive

I would like to backup my [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) configuration.

Which files do I need to backup?

Comment: It is just a guess but have you checked inside the `~/.config/` folder or even for a hidden folder in your `home` directory?

Comment: it would be nice to update your question to include that this approach can be used to reset kdenlive default settings (by deleting the file), there are lots of questions like that out there and only this one worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config file for kdenlive is located in

```
~/.kde/share/config/kdenliverc
```

And / or:

```
~/.config/kdenliverc
```

---

Additionally, there's also a directory

```
~/.kde/share/apps/kdenlive/
```

And

```
~/kdenlive
```

Which contains additional configuration data, including export profiles, video file information and so on, so you should back that up too.

---

To see the `.kde` directory, you'll need to enable "Show hidden files" in your file manager. In Nautilus (The default Ubuntu / Unity file manager), you can do so with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

Comment: What about the file `.config/kdenliverc`?

Comment: @orschiro I don't have that file there on my installation - but if it's there, you should back it up too. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Do you use KDE or Gnome/Unity? On Unity I don't have the folder `.kde`. Moreover, the folder `kdenlive` is placed directly in my home folder.

Comment: @orschiro I use MATE, although I also have KDE installed. In my case, I also have a `kdenlive` directory in my home folder, however, it doesn't contain any files.

Comment: Strange...For me it contains the folders `proxy, thumbs, titles` and a number of files `*.kdenlive`. I will back this one up, too!

Comment: @orschiro, Well, back it up too :-)

Comment: Maybe you can add this to the answer? `~/.kde/share/apps/kdenlive/` and/or `~/kdenlive`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If [Jonas Czech's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/783437/428566) doesn't work,  you might find the config file in

```
~/snap/kdenlive/common/.cache/kdenlive
```

or even

```
snap/kdenlive/91/.cache/
```

I was facing difficulty finding out the config location and end up using `find`. If above doesn't work you can also try this ...

```
$ find . -name kdenlive
```