# I have a problem with Kdenlive reset settings

Tags: apt, uninstall, reset, kdenlive

I have played on some settings and now it´s not working anymore. So I uninstalled it with `sudo apt-get purge kdenlive kdenlive-data` to make sure nothing is left from it. Next I reinstalled it and it's in the same settings witch are making this program unusable. I also tried a few other ways like remove it by the Software Center ore `sudo apt-get remove kdenlive`

If enyone cold help me that would be verry nice : )

Anthony

Comment: user settings are in your home directory and so purging and reinstalling will not help as user settings in home are not removed by purge. AV is complicated and without a better description of the problem hard to give you specific advice. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/783435/where-can-i-find-the-configuration-files-for-kdenlive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bodhi.zazen said, purging doesn't clear kdenlive settings in the home directory. To reset the settings, run

```
rm ~/.kde/share/config/kdenliverc ~/.config/kdenliverc
```

(It will be normal to receive an error that there is no such file or directory because your config file will only be stored in one of these)

In addition, if you have access to kdenlive, there is an option to reset settings with Settings>Configure Kdenlive...>Restore Defaults (At the bottom of the window)

Comment: U are a God EVAN

Comment: @AnthonyWebster No problem, glad it worked!